# Referencing Alphabetic characters in C# string

Tags: c#, regex, if-statement, foreach

I have a string that where I am trying to remove any characters that are not alphabetic. In the foreach loop below, I am wondering if there is a better way to reference the alphabetic characters without having to type each one of them out and without using the regex method.

```
foreach(char c in phrase) {
    if (!(c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c' || c == 'd' || c == 'e' || c == 'f' || c == 'g' || c == 'h' || c == 'i' ||
            c == 'j' || c == 'k' || c == 'l' || c == 'm' || c == 'n' || c == 'o' || c == 'p' || c == 'q' || c == 'r' || c == 's' ||
            c == 't' || c == 'u' || c == 'v' || c == 'w' || c == 'x' || c == 'y' || c == 'z')) {
        int i = phrase.IndexOf(c);
        phrase = phrase.Remove(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Having it written out that way seems sloppy and it can be time consuming.
Any Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: `without using the regex method` why tag `regex` ?

Comment: If you decide you want to still use the Regex method: `s.Replace(new Regex("[^a-z]"), string.Empty);` (case-sensitive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var alphaPhrase = new String(phrase.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

This will give you variable `alphaPhrase` with all the alphabets  from `phrase`

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried to measure performance of LINQ and Regex (with `RegexOptions.Compiled` set) approaches. It turns out Regex is more efficient *but only the first time you run the code*:

```
var nonAlpha = new Regex(@"\P{L}+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var phrase = "!@#$%^&*()_+=-0987654321`~qwerty{}|[]\';:\"/.,<>?";
var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
var alphaPhrase = new String(phrase.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
stopwatch.Stop();

var stopwatchRegex = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
stopwatchRegex.Start();
var alphaPhrase2 = nonAlpha.Replace(phrase, string.Empty);
stopwatchRegex.Stop();
```

Outputs (Run 2 is performed by halting code execution and dragging the arrow up to the `stopwatch` declaration line):

```
stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds      = 0.0117504 / (Run 2) 0.0000247
stopwatchRegex.Elapsed.TotalSeconds = 0.0026807 / (Run 2) 0.0012448
```